# pg_restore using PostGIS/PostgreSQL Dump Changes Data in Geography Column

Tags: postgresql, restore, spatial, postgis, pg-restore

Two PostGIS databases (PostGIS 3.0, PostgreSQL 13.1) were setup on two separate machines to be as close to each other as possible using Docker images.

A dump of the database was taken from the first machine using

```
pg_dump --host=db1.foo.com --dbname=foo --username=postgres -Fc --file=/tmp/foo.dump
```

and then restored on the database on the second machine using

```
pg_restore --clean --dbname=foo /tmp/foo.dump
```

When we view a query result using a GUI software TablePlus, we noticed that the column named `coordinates` of type `Geography` contains values that look very different after restoring.

**Query Result on 1st Machine (pg_dump source):**

`SELECT coordinates FROM locations LIMIT 5;`

[image]

**Query Result on 2nd Machine (after pg_restore):**

`SELECT coordinates FROM locations LIMIT 5;`

[image]

However, our app that queries this database for coordinate data appears to be plotting the data correctly on a map. This makes me think that the data on both machines are the same, but stored in different representation.

**Question:** Why did the `Geography` data values in the column `coordinates` changed, and how can we restore from the dump while keeping the original data values?

---

**Update:** Tried using `-b` when performing `pg_dump`, but the problem persist.

```
pg_dump --host=db1.foo.com --dbname=foo --username=postgres -Fc -b --file=/tmp/foo.dump
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first output is showing as [EWKT (Extended Well Known Text)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) while the second output is WKB (Well Known Binary). These are both standard representations of the internal geometry but are designed for different end users (human v machine).

To be honest I have never see PostGIS return WKT in a standard select statement, usually you would wrap the geometry in [`ST_AsTEXT`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) or [`ST_AsEWKT`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html) to see that.

Any way I think your data is just fine.